# Get bookmark value from URL calling classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, anchor

If I'm calling for example, http://www.mysite.asp?p1=2&p2=3#Bookmark  Does the browser invoke that #Bookmark after the "classic" ASP generates output?  It appears that it's not coming thru, the browser doesn't jump down to the bookmark.  I am suspicious it's getting "thrown out" by either ASP or the browser.  This acts the same on both FF and IE6.  Ideas?  Thanks Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 4):

Have you set the anchor name in the HTML markup?

For this #Bookmark to work you must have a link `<a name="Bookmark" ... ></a>`.

See [HTML Links - The name Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

Basic notes:

Tip: If a browser does not find the named anchor specified, it goes to the top of the document. No error occurs.

More on this:

http://thedailyreviewer.com/dotnet/view/bookmark-anchors-and-vbnet-103202803
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t96249-can-you-jump-to-an-anchor-on-postback.html

Comment: Yep, anchor tag is present in the output generated by the ASP.  I think ASP is interfering with applying the bookmark from the URL.